# How to get route path to load for <Link> component with onClick?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-router

I have set up a simple SPA using react, & react-router, and my routes have all been working fine. I introduced a Link in one of the child components with a path to one of my routes. The Link was changing the path in the URL, however when I added an onClick handler to have the view on the page update, the URL no longer displays the updated path. The content loads properly, but the URL doesn't show the user the new path/page hierarchy... I'll include my code, you'll see that I am using a callback function for the onClick... not sure if that is causing the problem? Or if it is an issue that the path includes a variable whose value is asynchronous to the onClick callback function... I'm a newbie, so please be descriptive in your solutions, TIA.

```
<div className="projPrev">
  <Link
    to={"/work/"+ this.backProjID(this.props.projectData.number)}
    onClick={this.goPrevProj}
  >
    <img
      src={"../Icon/Icon w Text/Previous.png"}
      alt="back arrow"
    />
  </Link>
</div>
```

this is my routing code...

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <div className="header">
            <Branding />
            <div className="navigation">
              <NavLink to="/work" activeClassName="current" className="notCurrent">Work</NavLink> 
              <NavLink exact to="/about" activeClassName="current" className="notCurrent">About</NavLink>
              <NavLink exact to="/contact" activeClassName="current" className="notCurrent">Contact</NavLink>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" render={() =><Redirect to='/work'/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/work" component={Work1}/>
              <Route path="/about" component={About1}/>
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact1}/>
              <Route path="/work/:projectID" exact render={ (props) => { return <ProjectContainer projectId={props.match.params.projectID} />} }  />
            </Switch>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

here is ProjectContainer.js

```
import React from "react";
import Project from "./Project.js";
var projData = require('./ProjData.js');

export default class ProjectContainer extends React.Component {

    state = {
        projID: "",
        number: "",
        name: "",
        heading: "",
        description: "",
        image: "",
        carousel_img1: "",
        carousel_img2: "",
        carousel_img3: "",
        carousel_blurb1: "",
        carousel_blurb2: "",
        carousel_blurb3: "",
    };


    componentDidMount () {
        console.log(this.props.projectId);
        if(this.state.projID !== this.props.projectId) {
            let obj = projData.find(obj => obj.projID === this.props.projectId);
            console.log(obj);
            this.setState(obj);
        }
    }

    submitHandler = (obj) => {
        this.setState(obj);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="projectContainer">
                <Project projectData={this.state} submitHandler={this.submitHandler}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

here is the Project.js component, it shows the goPrevProj function...

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
var projData = require('./ProjData.js');


export default class Project extends React.Component {


componentDidUpdate () {
    console.log(this.props.projectData);
}

backProjID = (currentProjNum) => {
    if (currentProjNum === 1){
        const prevProjNum = 11;
        const prevObj = projData.find(obj => obj.number === prevProjNum);
        return prevObj.projID;
    }
    else if (currentProjNum >1 && currentProjNum < 12){
        const prevProjNum = currentProjNum-1;
        const prevObj = projData.find(obj => obj.number === prevProjNum);
        return prevObj.projID;
    }

}

goPrevProj = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let currentProjNum = this.props.projectData.number;
    if (currentProjNum === 1){
        const prevProjNum = 11; 
        const prevObj = projData.find(obj => obj.number === prevProjNum); 
        this.props.submitHandler(prevObj); 
    }               
    else if (currentProjNum >1 && currentProjNum < 12){
        const prevProjNum = currentProjNum-1;
        const prevObj = projData.find(obj => obj.number === prevProjNum); 

        this.props.submitHandler(prevObj); 
    }
    else {
        console.log("There's an error with the eventhandler");
    }

}

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="projMain">
                    <div className="projNav">
                        <div className="projPrev">
                        {console.log(this.backProjID(this.props.projectData.number))};
                            <Link to={"/work/"+ this.backProjID(this.props.projectData.number)} onClick={this.goPrevProj}><img src={"../Icon/Icon w Text/Previous.png"} alt="back arrow"/></Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projNum">{this.props.projectData.number}</div>
                        <div className="projNext"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="projInfo">
                        <div className="projName">{this.props.projectData.name}</div>
                        <div className="projHeading">{this.props.projectData.heading}</div>
                        <div className="projDescription">{this.props.projectData.description}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="projImage">
                        <img src={this.props.projectData.image} alt="baseball players"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="projDetailTab">
                    <div className="tabRectangleLeft">
                        <div className="tabTitle"></div>
                        <div className="tabExpandClose"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="tabRectangleRight"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="projDevInfo">
                    <div className="rectangle"></div>
                    <div className="projDevImage">
                        {/* insert the image tag here */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="blurbContainer">
                        <div className="blurb"></div>
                        <div className="controlsContainer">
                            <div className="carouselControls">
                                <div className="prevSlide"></div>
                                <div className="slide1Box"></div>
                                <div className="slide2Box"></div>
                                <div className="slide3Box"></div>
                                <div className="nextSlide"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you revert the addition of the `onClick` handler does the Link again function correctly? You can at least determine if the `to` prop is computed correctly.

Comment: @DrewReese yes if I remove the onClick, the URL updates with the correct path, however none of the content on the page updates as the onClick was handling the content update

Comment: Is this just a back button? Do you mind sharing your routing code? I suspect you may not be using react-router to its full potential, i.e. using route params to use URL match params (like the projectID) to do things when the component for *that* page is loaded.

Comment: sure, that is very possible since I'm super new to this...

Comment: Instead of adding page updates on `onClick` you should be adding it onMount of the component rendered when the new url is updated

Comment: Can you share the code for `this.goPrevProj`

Comment: Also please share `ProjectContainer` component.

Comment: @Jagrati can you elaborate on what you mean by "Instead of adding page updates on onClick you should be adding it onMount of the component rendered when the new url is updated". I couldn't find any lifecycle methods called onMount()...

Comment: @DrewReese yes it is meant to be a simple back button for the content rendering specifically in the child component Project.js

Comment: Jagrati just means "when the component mounts"

Comment: in case anyone else runs into this issue, I realized the problem was that my routes were in a parent component to State, so when I would setState, the routes wouldn't register the re-render. I solved by lifting State up and was able to removed the onClick I had been using in the Link

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for the help.